# AngularJS Controller Cannot Properly Invoke Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this

I am using Angular 1.6 and am having trouble trying to get a controller to call a function I have passed in. In my example below, I have `homepage.html` which is passing a function into `<image-selector>`. I want `<image-selector>` to call the passed-in function which will update the parent when the image has been changed. `HomepageCtrl` will then call its own function `updateState()` to process the data.

The problem is that `HomepageCtrl` fails to call `updateState()` because `this.updateState()` in `onImageChange()` is undefined. I suspect that the issue is caused because `ImageSelectorCtrl` is invoking `onImageChange()` so `this` is pointed to the `ImageSelectorCtrl` instead of `HomepageCtrl`.

I am wondering how I would fix this issue so `ImageSelectorCtrl` can invoke `onImageChange()` which will then call `updateState()`?

```
// homepage.js
import homepageHtml from './homepage.html';
class HomepageCtrl {
    constructor() {
    }

    onImageChange(newImage) {
        this.updateState({newImage: processImage(newImage)}); // console error: cannot read property of 'updateState' of undefined
    }

    updateState(options) {
        console.log('Updating state...');
    }
}
export const Homepage = {
    template: homepageHtml,
    controller: HomepageCtrl
};


// homepage.html
<div class="homepage">
    <image-selector on-change="$ctrl.onImageChange"></image-selector>
</div>


// imageSelector.js
import imageSelectorHtml from './image-selector.html';
class ImageSelectorCtrl {
    constructor() {
        this.imageUrl;
    }

    onChange() {
        this.onChange()(imageUrl);
    }
}
export const ImageSelector = {
    bindings: {
        onChange: '&'
    },
    template: imageSelectorHtml,
    controller: ImageSelectorCtrl
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try binding this to your class methods as they are being executed in a different context.

```
 class HomepageCtrl {
    constructor() {
      this.onImageChange = this.onImageChange.bind(this)
      this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this)
    }

    onImageChange(newImage) {
        this.updateState({newImage: processImage(newImage)}); // console error: cannot read property of 'updateState' of undefined
    }

    updateState(options) {
        console.log('Updating state...');
    }
}
```